# Download Speed is unusually slow?

Tags: downloads, ethernet

On a internet speed test I get on average 20 download and 2 upload, however when I'm trying to actually download something, be it updates, or just recently a Kali Linux .iso file it only downloads at a <1mbps speed. When I boot into Windows 8 instead my download speeds are normal, things download at the average 20mbps download speed like it says it should. Can anyone help?
I'm testing all of this on a direct Ethernet connection, so I don’t see why I’d get poor connection.

Comment: If speed tests indicate that connection is fast, but download is not, it could be a problem with storage. You could try `time dd if=/dev/zero of=your/download/directory/testfile bs=1M count=1024`. This will drop 1 GB zeroes in `testfile` and meassures the time. Other candidates: Virus scanners (either on your machine or possibly the router), restrictive Quality-of-Service settings (again your machine or the router).

Comment: I was having the same issue on a fresh install of 12.04 lts server with lxde. turns out, encrypting the home directory grinds writing to the dowload folder to a stand still. i googled and it seems to be an issue with lxde. my downloads are about 50 kbs with chromium. In the command line, using apt-get im pulling 1.8 mbs, which is right on par with what my wind0ze machine pulls. Maybe that's your problem as well.